# How to prevent async - await freezing in javascript?

Tags: javascript, adonisjs-ace

Good day I have a custom adonisjs command that pulls from an API.

```
async handle (args, options) {
    // Status 
    // Open = 1979

    // Get all jobs with open status.
    const pullJobController = new PullJobsFromJobAdderController;
    let token = await pullJobController.get_token();

    if(token){
        const jobs = await this._getOpenJobs('https://jobs/open-jobs', token , 1979);
    }
}

async _getOpenJobs(url, accessToken, status) {
        url = url + '?statusId=' + status
        const headers = {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
        }

        const options = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: url,
            headers: headers
        }

        return (await rp(options).then(function (result) {
            return {
                status: true,
                info: JSON.parse(result)
            }
            
        }).catch(function (error) {
            return {
                status: false
            }
        }));

    } // _getOpenJobs()
```

PullJobsFromJobAdderController

```
async get_token()
    {
        // This works if directly returning the token.
        // return "9ade34acxxa4265fxx4b5x6ss7fs61ez";  

        const settings = await this.settings();
        const jobAdderObject = new this.JobAdder(settings.jobadder['client.id'], settings.jobadder['client.secret'])
        const jobadderOauthObject = this.model('JobadderOauth');
        
        const accessInfo = await jobadderOauthObject.jobdderLatestAccess();

        let isAccessExpired = await this.checkAccessValidity(accessInfo.created_at);
        let accessToken = accessInfo.access_token;
        let apiEndpoint = accessInfo.api_endpoint;
        
        if(isAccessExpired === true){
            let refreshTokenInfo = await jobAdderObject.refrehToken(accessInfo.refresh_token)

            if (refreshTokenInfo.status === true) {
                let refreshTokenDetails = JSON.parse(refreshTokenInfo.info)
                accessToken = refreshTokenDetails.access_token
                apiEndpoint = refreshTokenDetails.api

                await jobadderOauthObject.create({
                    code: accessInfo.code,
                    access_token: refreshTokenDetails.access_token,
                    refresh_token: refreshTokenDetails.refresh_token,
                    scope: 'read write offline_access',
                    api_endpoint: refreshTokenDetails.api
                })
            }
        }
        
        return accessToken;
    } // get_token()
```

The function async get_token works as expected, it supplies me with a fresh token to be used by the adonisjs command. However it freezes after running the command.

But if I return the string token directly. The custom command handle() works as expected and terminates after running.

Scenario 1: (Directly returning the token string from PullJobsFromJobAdderController)

1. I run my custom command "adonis pull:jobs" and it runs as expected displaying in the terminal the result of the pulled data from the api.
2. Terminal is ready to accept another command.
   [image]

Scenario 2: (Comment out the directly returned string token from PullJobsFromJobAdderController)

1. I run my custom command "adonis pull:jobs" and it runs as expected
   displaying in the terminal the result of the pulled data from the
   api.
2. Terminal is not accepting commands until I press ctrl+c and terminate the current job/command.
   [image]

Perhaps I am missing something regarding async await calls.

Can someone point / help me to the right direction?

TIA

Comment: *what "freezes after running" which "command"*? async/await never freezes - something, somewhere, that you are `await`ing on is returning a Promise that never resolves ...

Comment: My apologies @Bravo, edited the question to explain both scenarios.

Comment: _"Comment out the directly returned string token from PullJobsFromJobAdderController"_... it's hard to tell what you mean by this. Can you actually show these two scenarios as code changes?

Comment: i don't know what language that is, but it's not Javascript. perhaps it is TypeScript or CoffeeScript or something like that, idk, but not JS.

Comment: @hanshenrik what makes you say that? At a cursory glance, it looks like plain old JavaScript to me

Comment: @hanshenrik - looks like plain ol' javascript to me - which part confuses you?

Comment: @Phil ```async handle (args, options) {}``` is not valid syntax. it would be valid if it was ```async function handle (args, options) {}```, but it's not

Comment: @hanshenrik ah, right. I just assumed OP cut that particular snippet out of an object or class. The `this._getOpenJobs` further down indicates the same

Comment: Should be `const pullJobController = new PullJobsFromJobAdderController();` (with brackets) surely?

Comment: @seesharper - no - perfectly valid syntax

Comment: @Bravo yes, PullJobsFromJobAdderController is my code and it works fine from another module.

@Phil What I meant of commenting out is this line ```return "9ade34acxxa4265fxx4b5x6ss7fs61ez"; ``` (Scenario 2)

Comment: Why not @Bravo? It's calling a constructor, or should be...

Comment: Ah interesting, never noticed the parentheses were optional if there are no parameters.

Comment: @Bravo I tried adding this to the handle(): 
```try{
            let token = await pullJobController.get_token();
            console.log(token);

            if(token){
                const jobs = await this._getOpenJobs('https://jobs/open-jobs', token , 1979);
                console.log(jobs);
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }```

how ever no errors were returned... still the terminal wont accept another command unless I manually terminate the running process.

Comment: @Bravo does console.log(token); execute? yes it does.

After getting the token from ```pullJobController.get_token()``` the next promise is ``` this._getOpenJobs()``` but i think it is resolving since it returns the API response, and in addition it works as expected if the ```pullJobController.get_token();``` returns a hard-coded token string.

Comment: @Bravo does console.log(token); execute? Yes it does...
If so, what is the code for this._getOpenJobs - did you write it? Yes I wrote it. Ill post it.

Comment: Ok, so what is the code for `rp` function

Comment: @Bravo it is a package from here: https://github.com/request/request-promise

Comment: put some console.log's in that function to see how far along it's going ... I assume `console.log(jobs)` is NOT happening?

Comment: @bravo console.log(jobs) work... i can see the response from the API.
https://im.ge/i/NANZ9

its just that the terminal seems to freeze that i need to manually exit it to type another command

Comment: oh, no idea what this `terminal` you keep going on about is, so the problem is somewhere else

Comment: @Bravo I think it is from the async await since the terminal not terminating the job automatically only happens if i comment out ```return "9ade34acxxa4265fxx4b5x6ss7fs61ez";``` from ```PullJobsFromJobAdderController```

Thanks BTW @Bravo

Comment: if jobs is logged, that's after the last await - so noting to do with async await

Comment: will process.exit() after console.log(jobs) be enough? Since i just need a token from the ```pullJobController.get_token();``` and nothing else, since it returns a token i dont need it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I got it, for anyone else having this kind of problem with adonis commands:
wrap the task inside your handle in a try... catch block then always have Database.close() and process.exit() in finally.